# XSLt blank namespace

Tags: xslt

i have xml i want to copy as is like (check xmlns="" and tags. i want to create as is .

The total calculation is taken care. only this issue . it is valid . still client want the expected format to be like that. any help greatly appreciated.
three tasks

1)I need to add namespace  Employees xmnls="1.2" xmlns:xsi="3" xsi:schemalocation="4">
2)generating tag like this in the output xml  not 
3)need to avoid xmlns=""

any help in advance greatly appreciated
rameshkumar singh

**Input.xml**

```
    <Employees>
            <employee>
             <dept>1</dept>
              <sec></sec>
            </employee>
            <employee>
               <dept>2</dept>
              <sec></sec>
            </employee>
    </Employees>

Expected.XML

         <Employees xmnls="1.2" xmlns:xsi="3" xsi:schemalocation="4">
            <totalemp>2</totalemp>
           <employee>
              <dept>1</dept>
              <sec></sec>
            <employee>
              <employee>
                   <dept>2</dept>
                    <sec></sec>
                 <employee>
              </Employees>


actual.XML
               <Employees>
                    <totalemp>2</totalemp>
                        <employee xmlns="">
                        <dept>1</dept>
                          <sec/>
                        </employee>
                         <employee>
                           <dept>2</dept>
                              <sec/>
                           <employee>
                 </Employees>
```

Comment: Can you generate correct XML directly instead of trying to use XSLT to convert? (BTW, your "shift" key seems to be broken as sentences have random capitalization)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="3">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" priority="2">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="1.2">
            <xsl:if test="self::Employees">
                <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemalocation">4</xsl:attribute>          
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You apply the identity transformation as a default and then override it for elements to give them a new **namespace** as well as a special attribute for the `Employees` node. I chose to add an `if` statement but you also can move that logic into another template that matches `Employees`. I just didn't want to repeat the whole `xsl:element` thing twice. Matter of taste really.

When I apply this transformation to your input document I end up with:

```
<Employees xmlns="1.2" xmlns:xsi="3" xsi:schemalocation="4">
    <employee>
        <dept>1</dept>
        <sec/>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <dept>2</dept>
        <sec/>
    </employee>
</Employees>
```

You had the `xmlns=""` in your result likely because you weren't recreating all elements in that new namespace. Also, to be able to add the `xsi:schemalocation` attribute you need to declare the `xsi` namespace on the transformation document.

Answer (score 0):

**This short and simple transformation (has minimum number of templates and doesn't use any explicit XSLT conditional instructions, no `xsl:attribute` or `priority` attributes):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xsi="3" xsi:schemalocation="4">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="1.2">
   <xsl:copy-of select=
   "document('')/*[not(current()/../..)]
                        /@xsi:schemalocation"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Employees>
    <employee>
        <dept>1</dept>
        <sec></sec>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <dept>2</dept>
        <sec></sec>
    </employee>
</Employees>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Employees xmlns="1.2" xmlns:xsi="3" xsi:schemalocation="4">
   <employee>
      <dept>1</dept>
      <sec/>
   </employee>
   <employee>
      <dept>2</dept>
      <sec/>
   </employee>
</Employees>
```

Comment: i expected the result as  <sec></sec>
 not as <sec/>

Comment: @RameshSingh: The two are equivalent. Both represent a `sec` element with no children. The exact lexical representation cannot be controlled from within a transformation and often differs form one XSLT processor to another. If this is really so important to you, you may trick the XSLT processor by: `<xsl:template match="sec[not(node())]><sec><xsl:value-of select="/.."/></sec></xsl:template>`

Comment: i cant trick it, in my real requirement i have around 1000 xml tags like that. my client wants the tag <sec></sec> in that fashion. i tried Method=html  using copy-of i get xmlns="" issue. i dont know how to handle both together

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, I would argue that you traded off some readability :)

Comment: @RameshSingh, you can extend Dimitre suggestion and replace the `sec` "hardcode" with `<xsl:element name="local-name()">...</xsl:element>`. It should help you with the `1000 xml tags`

Comment: @PavelVeller: Yes, I know what you mean ... :)